# Spring Cloud Data Flow + Kubernetes, asking for the task pod to be deployed on non-default namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-kubernetes, spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes

I have a setup with `scdf-server` on `kubernetes` working fine, it deploys each task in an on-demand pod on the very same default namespace, the one that hosts the `scdf-server` pod.

Now, I need to deploy a pod in another namespace and I can't find the argument/property to use in the `scdf server dashboard` for the pod to be created in the given namespace. Does anybody know how to find that? I tried `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.namespace, deployer.kubernetes.namespace, spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.environmentVariables, deployer.<app>.kubernetes.namespace, spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.namespace, scheduler.kubernetes.environmentVariables SPRING_CLOUD_SCHEDULER_KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE`... as both 'properties' and 'arguments' text boxes...